# How to handle white space in command line?Like: GOMAKE=${GOGO}(white space here) build

Tags: autoconf

### I want to compile thrift 0.8 to support go1(golang version 1) .Before go1,there are two command:goinstall and gomake,so lines in configure script like this:

```
GOMAKE=${GOBIN}/gomake
GOINSTALL=${GOBIN}/goinstall
```

---

### but as of go1,"go install" and "go build" replaced "goinstall" and "gomake",I found some guy changed thrift configure script to:

```
GOGO=${GOBIN}/go
GOMAKE=${GOGO} build
GOINSTALL=${GOGO} install
```

---

### but when I try to run script with: ./configure,I got:

```
./configure: line 18067: build: command not found 
install: missing file operand
Try `install --help' for more information.
checking for 6g... /6g
checking for 6l... /6l
```

---

Not sure,but I think

```
"./configure: line 18067: build: command not found"
```

means white space within "GOMAKE=${GOGO} build" can't be handled,right?Anyone can help to make this work?Thanks

---

### I tried to edit configure.ac from:

```
 GOGO=${GOBIN}/go
 GOMAKE=${GOGO} build
 GOINSTALL=${GOGO} install
```

---

### to

```
GOGO=${GOBIN}/go
GOMAKE="${GOGO} build"
GOINSTALL="${GOGO} install"
```

---

Then regenerate configure script,and run it.It seems modified lines were ignored directly:

---

```
checking for go... /home/alex/go/bin/go
(*************checking goinstall and gomake should be here,but not)
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
```

Comment: If "some guy" is actually a human being that modified an autoconf generated configure script, then the solution is to fix the bad edits and add quotes on the assignments.  More likely, you need to look in `configure.ac` for assignments to GOMAKE and GOINSTALL and add the necessary quotes.

Comment: Why would configure check for `go`, `gomake` and `goinstall`?  Did you call any macro to check for those? If so, show us the relevant code.

Comment: Thrift's go supporting comes from this project:https://github.com/pomack/thrift4go,it doesn't support go1.And some guy add go1 supporting here:https://github.com/yanatan16/thrift4go,that three lines to check goinstall and gomake comes from this modified project.